# fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Am using the free jqgrid , to keep it short, am getting method not found on fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding  when I try to set the height of the jqgrid via the below code in beforeProcessing().

```
$grid.setGridHeight(200).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

The reason I need to set the height is, when rownNum is <10, i want height as auto. but wen the rowNum is >10, i need the grid to have  a vertical scrollbar. But when setting this height, I get to see the javascript error which says, fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding is not an object or property.

**error:
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding' 
jquery.jqgrid.min.js, line 202 character 381**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the origin of your problem could be wrong usage of `setGridHeight` or the usage of `setGridHeight` **before** you created the grid in `$grid` (for example `$grid` can be wrong and you should use `$(this)` instead). You didn't posted **where** in your code you use the lines. Free jqGrid set `fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding` property of `$grid[0]` during creating of the grid (before `onInitGrid` is called).

One more important remark: you should be always very carefully in the usage of `reloadGrid` inside of other callbacks. You should understand the `reloadGrid` works **synchronously**. It means that the next line after `reloadGrid` will be executed *after* `trigger("reloadGrid")` is finished. For example you loads the 5-th page returned from the server. The call of `trigger("reloadGrid")` will reset `page` parameter of jqGrid, it can change `datatype`, place new Ajax request and so on. So **I strictly recommend to use `trigger("reloadGrid")` only inside of `setTimeout`**. In the way you can allow jqGrid to process the current request till the end and *later* make reloading:

```js
$grid.setGridHeight(200);
setTimeout(function () {
    $grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
}, 50);
```

It the above will not help then you should 1) use `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` to report the error; 2) write which version of free jqGrid you use (4.9.1, 4.9 or the current code from GitHub); 3) post more full example which can be used *to reproduce* the problem. One can easy localize the origin of the problem by debugging of the code, but one have to guess about the reason if one see only one line of code (or some small code fragment).

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I got it resolved.. I was actually doing a blunder where in before the grid is completely initialized I was trying to perform some action on the grid under the window.resize function.. Just ensured that the resize call is made only after the grid is ready.